# Can I edit the NAMESPACE file without rebuilding the package?

Tags: r, namespaces

I've got an existing package in my library, but when the package was built one function was omitted from the `export` commands in the `NAMESPACE` file.  I was hoping that I could simply add another line to the file but it appears that the namespace definitions, despite being in a text file, are 'baked in' to the package at build time.   I've tried both adding and removing `export` commands but the loaded namespace list doesn't change.
I've made sure to detach and unload the package in question, then restart `R` (3.3.1) clean.
So, do I have to rebuild, or am I missing some simple step?

(for those wondering, I did rebuild the  package w/ the new namespace commands, and it worked).

Comment: I think not. If the package doesn't have compiled code, though, then you don't need any extra build tools to install it ... or, at a pinch, you could edit the DESCRIPTION file to change the maintainer to yourself, and send it off to ftp.win-builder.r-project.org to build a Windows binary ...

Comment: @BenBolker thanks -- I installed `rtools` and the other toys required, and successfully  rebuilt the package (no compiled code).

Comment: you could also do something like `library(package); foo <- package:::foo` and then use it as if it had been exported.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes, I could for myself, but I sure wouldn't impose that on users of a published package :-)

Comment: Gotcha. Wasn't sure your intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben Bolker suggested, the answer ([Bettridge's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betteridge%27s_law_of_headlines) wins again!) is "no."  Despite the existence of an editable text file in a package's tarball, the export list is read from one of the binaries ('foo.rdb' or 'foo.rdx' is my guess) and cannot be changed without rebuilding the package.